# writing stdout to a file from execvp

Tags: c, redirect, fork, execvp, dup2

Why is it that execvp isnt writing to the redirected STDOUT?
I tried using printf() as a test within this block, and that writes exactly where it should, which is in the file that I redirected STDOUT to.

edit: I changed the code, and added my implementation of makesubcommand, and added some debugging messages.

```
pid = fork();
    wait(0);
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        fd = open(subargs[next_redirect + 1], O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_WRONLY, 0644);
        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd);
        //create sub-command
        int val = (next_redirect - (last_redirect + 1));
        fprintf(stderr,"subcommand will have %i indexes\n", val);
        char* subcommand[val];
        makesubcommand(subcommand, subargs, last_redirect + 1, next_redirect);
        execvp(subcommand[0], subcommand);
        fprintf(stderr,"execvp failed\n");
    }
    last_redirect = next_redirect;
    next_redirect = getnextredirect(subargs, last_redirect+2, subargc);
```

heres makesubcommand(4):

```
void makesubcommand(char** newcommand, char** oldcommand, int lowerbound, int upperbound)
{
    int i;
    fprintf(stderr, "lowerbound: %i upperbound: %i\n",lowerbound, upperbound);
    for(i = lowerbound; i < upperbound; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"subarg[%i]: %s\n", (i-lowerbound), oldcommand[i]);
        newcommand[i - lowerbound] = oldcommand[i];
    }
    for(i = lowerbound; i < upperbound; i++)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "newcommand[%i] = %s\n",(i - lowerbound), newcommand[i]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "it worked\n");
}
```

heres a testrun:

```
{12425}/home/chris/2240New/WMU-CS2240/A3_Shell$ ls > a
subcommand will have 1 indexes
lowerbound: 0 upperbound: 1
subarg[0]: ls
newcommand[0] = ls
it worked
execvp failed
```

Comment: Show the actual print that isn't working.

Comment: When execvp executes, its output should go to fd, but it seems not to go anywhere. That is what isn't working. if I remove the comments before the printf, my file contains "this is a test\n".

Comment: How is `subcommand` populated ?

Comment: This is a snippet of code from a shell that I'm writing. if I input "grep hamster > a", then subcommand will simply be {"grep","hamster"}  for testing, I'm using ls > a, so subcommand will be {"ls"}. makesubcommand(4) is tested and works properly.

Comment: I did some editing, making my code more transparent, and added some debugging messages sent to stderr. Still looking for a solution but I do believe that the problem is in subcommand now :(

Comment: Does `subcommand` end with `NULL` ?

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being that I needed to allocate memory for the subcommand. malloc did the trick!